# POST Request works in POSTMAN but not in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, rest, postman

I have request witch works in postman, but when I try it in my VB.net application, then response.content is empty and statusCode=  500 InternalServerError

This is my code:

```
    Public Function postData(ByVal dictData As Dictionary(Of String, Object)) As Boolean
        Dim lresponse As IRestResponse
        Dim body() As Byte
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType((768 Or 3072), System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)

        Try
            Dim client As New RestClient(lURL)
            client.Timeout = -1

            Dim request As New RestRequest(Method.POST)
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & lToken.AccessToken)
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")

            body = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictData, Formatting.Indented))

            request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody)
            lresponse = client.Execute(request)

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return False
    End Function
```

Comment: If the response doesn't contain any information about why it failed then I imagine your options are (1) carefully compare this request with the Postman one and find any differences, and (2) contact the owner of the server for support with integrating to that service.  There's really nothing *we* can do here.  We know nothing about the system to which you're sending the request and we know nothing about the error occurring on that system.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I find mistake in code and now it works fine. But now my problem is response content is in gzip format. I ad '            request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
'
But it doesnt work.

Comment: You can initialize your `RestClient` with a `RestClientOption` object, which includes `AutomaticDecompression` -- The Header you have set tells the Server that you can handle those compression methods -- Not clear why you have this: `CType((768 Or 3072)`. Do you have a very old .NET Framework version? If that's the case, it's time to update. Otherwise, set it explicitly to `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`, nobody uses TLS 1.1 anymore (well, maybe *internally*)

Comment: Thank You, RestClientOption helped.

Yes, it's .NET 4. I know it's time to update, but it is huge app and it would take a very long time to go to new framework and I don't have time and there aren't enough of us in the company for now.